# Separating collections in mongodb database that share a 1-to-1 relationship

Tags: database, mongodb

I am using mongodb as the database for a project I've been working on and in the database I have a "user" collection and an "account" collection. Every user has one account and every account has a "user" field that is the _id of the corresponding user. The reason I separated these into two collections is because I thought it made sense to keep the user's sensitive data (password, email, legal name, etc.) separate from the account data (things like interests, followers, username, etc.). Also the account collection has a lot of fields so it just seemed easier to not over-saturate the "user" collection with data.

So, my question is - Now that I essentially have 2 collections pointing to the same user, should I use the "user._id" to query both users and accounts? Since each account has a unique "user" field, is there a reason to query those accounts with their own _id property? It seems odd to keep track of two different _id's on the frontend and conditionally send either the user._id or account._id.

The two main drawbacks I have found when using the user._id to query both users and accounts is:

1. When querying account data, I have to almost always make sure I send the "user" field so I have that id on the front end.
2. If in the future, I wanted to add the ability for users to create multiple accounts, I would have to change the code to now fetch account data using the "account._id".

Hopefully that all makes sense, and maybe it doesn't even make sense for me to separate those collections. Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: What exactly are you seeking help with, please give the number of fields that you have for both the collections, if possible a representation of how calls are made. Are you calling both the collections together all the time? The followers fields, is it an array, if yes what's the max size?

Comment: You can do either solution with the pros and cons as you said.